# How can CVE-2016-2324 and -2315 be mitigated on Mac OS X?

Tags: vulnerability, macos, cve, git

[The recent `git` remote execution vulnerability](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2016/q1/645) states all git clients with version <2.7.1 are vulnerable and that most linux distributions have included the fixes already.

However, as of today,

> ```
> $ git --version
> git version 2.6.4 (Apple Git-63)
> $
> ```

on an up-to-date, out of the box Mac OS X dev machine.

Does this then leave most of the developers on Mac OS X that are using the apple developer tools out of the box vulnerable to this attack?

What can be done, other than

- manually installing an newer `git` client or
- not using `git` for foreign repositories at the moment?

Comment: Your question appears to be if using old software with a known security issue is a security risk

Comment: My question is: What can be done when the software from the default ecosystem is old and no security fixes are provided?

Comment: If that is your question, you need to edit your title. Secondly, at the time of this writing, there is no higher version than the one you have installed for Macs. The only options are the ones you outlined.

Comment: Apple's version number of an executable does not necessarily correspond to the "mainstream" version numbers of an executable, as Apple's forks sometimes get security fixes to older versions. But I don't want to confuse the issue here because I'm pretty sure git is **not** one of them, and `git version 2.6.4 (Apple Git-63)` **does** indicate the bug is unfixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most developers I know who are using OS X are using Homebrew for a variety of reasons; in addition to providing easy installation of tools not available from Apple, the updated versions of Apple-provided tools provide bugfixes and security fixes.  And yes, [Homebrew is currently distributing git 2.7.4](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/git.rb).

Comment: Right; that's covered by "manually installing a newer version of git", or at least I thought it would be (that's what I have done;))

Comment: It depends on what you consider manual.  It's certainly less manual than downloading the git source and compiling it.  It *is* more manual than running Apple's global software update, but only if you haven't already installed it via homebrew, in which case it will get included in a 'brew upgrade' along with anything else out of date.  So I guess my perspective is that, for things Apple doesn't really care about, *pro-actively* it's a good idea to install them through a system like Homebrew so that you'll be prepared in the case of a vulnerability like this one.

Comment: That might pretty much cover all of apples' tools that come bundled with Xcode.

Comment: My question is whether using homebrew to update git will fully protect an end user. I can see that the `$PATH` variable has `/usr/local/bin` first, so no problem there for command line usage. However, not sure whether Xcode and other tools like SourceTree and Kraken would be protected? Opinion on that would be very appreciated.

Comment: Update: `brew install git` works just fine, but `xcrun --find git` still resolves to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git` sadly.